# Unable to join Azure Windows Server VM to local domain

Tags: azure, virtual-machines, domain-controller

I'm trying to get my Azure Windows Server VM to connect to my local AD.

I've already created a Site to Site VPN Gateway and connected both the DC (172.16.1.5) and VM (172.16.1.4) and I've confirmed that both can ping each other.

DNS of the VM is set to 172.16.1.5 via Azure Control Panel > Virtual networks > *vnet group* > *vm v-nic* > DNS servers

[image]

I tried a tracert on the VM but it couldn't resolve the domain but it does on the DC.

If it helps, my local network is 10.1.1.x, and the DC's DNS are 10.1.1.2 [Primary] (its local IP) and 127.0.0.1 [Secondary]

Comment: vpn is established?

Comment: You've said that the ip address of the DC is 172.16.1.5 and you've said that it is 10.1.1.2. Which is it? Both? If so, is the DNS server on the DC listening on ip address 172.16.1.5? If not, then that's your problem.